# How can I take string from input field and use it to calculate sum of the array?

Tags: c#

I am working on my app using Unity3D, and I am trying to get the user input string from the input filed then use that string to calculate the total sum by applying values from variables, but just cannot get to work. I have this

```
int B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U;

int characterLength = 0;
int numberLength = 0;

List<int> fomulaList = new List<int>();
List<int> numberList = new List<int>();

foreach (char c in charactersField.text)
{
    characterLength++;
    fomulaList.Add(c);

    Debug.Log(c);
 }

formulaArray = fomulaList.ToArray();

Debug.Log("Formula Length: " + formulaArray.Length + " " + formulaArray[0].ToString("D1") + " " + formulaArray[1].ToString("D1"));
```

Let's say: I typed in BC, and when I print out the DebugLog I got

Formula Length: 2 66 67

which is fine

```
foreach (char c in numbersField.text)
{
    numberLength++;

    Debug.Log(c);
}

for (int i = 0; i < winningNumberArray.Length; i++)
{
    B = winningNumberArray[i] / 100000;                 //100000
    C = (winningNumberArray[i] % 100000) / 10000;       //10000
    D = (winningNumberArray[i] % 10000) / 1000;         //1000
    E = (winningNumberArray[i] % 1000) / 100;           //100
    F = (winningNumberArray[i] % 100) / 10;             //10
    G = winningNumberArray[i] % 10;                     //1

    H = twoNumberArray[i] / 10;                         //10
    I = twoNumberArray[i] % 10;                         //1

    J = firstThreeNumberArray[i] / 100;                 //100
    K = (firstThreeNumberArray[i] % 100) / 10;          //10
    L = firstThreeNumberArray[i] % 10;                  //1

    M = secondThreeNumberArray[i] / 100;                //100
    N = (secondThreeNumberArray[i] % 100) / 10;         //10
    O = secondThreeNumberArray[i] % 10;                 //1

    P = thirdThreeNumberArray[i] / 100;                 //100
    Q = (thirdThreeNumberArray[i] % 100) / 10;          //10
    R = thirdThreeNumberArray[i] % 10;                  //1

    S = fourthThreeNumberArray[i] / 100;                //100
    T = (fourthThreeNumberArray[i] % 100) / 10;         //10
    U = fourthThreeNumberArray[i] % 10;                 //1

    int sum = formulaArray.Sum();

    Debug.Log("Sum: " + sum.ToString());
```

But when I print out the to I got

Sum: 133

It seems to me that the values for B and C are not from

B = winningNumberArray[i] / 100000;
C = (winningNumberArray[i] % 100000) / 10000;

How can I solve this?

Comment: `It seems to me that the values for B and C are not from

B = winningNumberArray[i] / 100000;
C = (winningNumberArray[i] % 100000) / 10000;`

They are, its in the code. Your problem is somewhere else. And what do B and C have to do with the sum? I don't see them in the formulaArray

Comment: Let's say the formulaArray = { B, C}, the sum then should be B+C, and the values for B and C should be assigned for winningNumberArray[i] / 100000 and (winningNumberArray[i] % 100000) / 10000.

Comment: @SuphavanhMahathirash Ints are value types, if you put them in an array and change them (instead of the array item) the array item will not update

Comment: Could you add the missing code to have a minimal and verifiable example? Where does `winningNumberArray` come from? Moreover, B, C, etc. are defined as int so when you do `winningNumberArray[i] / 100000` the result is transformed to an int which could be 0 if 'winningNumberArray[i]' < 100000

Comment: Using Dictionary<char, int> does the trick. Thank you!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely that you are confusing the `char` `'B'` with the variable `B`. Despite the similarities, they are completely unrelated.

It sounds like what you are trying to do is take user input, and get a particular value based on that user input. The right data structure for that, generally, in C# is a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

In your case you would want:

```
Dictionary<char,int>
```

where `char` is the key (e.g. `'A'` or `'B'`) and `int` is the value you are currently adding to your `A` or `B` variables).